# keras model fit: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'method'>, <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, fingerprint

When running a fingerprint code from kaggle
link here
[fingerprint recognition](https://www.kaggle.com/kairess/fingerprint-recognition)

```
 history = model.fit(train_gen, epochs=15, validation_data=val_gen)
```

I received the following error :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXMd7.jpg)

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f3de859cc6e5> in <module>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(train_gen, epochs=15, validation_data=val_gen)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
976         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
977         "input: {}, {}".format(
 978             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
979   elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
980     raise RuntimeError(
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class '__main__.DataGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

Can someone help me solve this issue?

Comment: It may be the case that one or more of your images are in a format that tensorflow can not process.. For example the ImageataGenerator can only handle PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM or TIF images.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is from DataGenerator class.
Change your import as

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
```

or
DataGenerator class should be

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
   ....
```